# reflow text instead of scroll text upon zooming in in mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

I have a webapp which is static reading content, and I want the following to happen on mobile, the user should be able to resize, and make the text bigger, but under no circumstances should they ever be forced to scroll horizontally, instead the text should reflow.  I want the text to take up 100% of the available screen width.  This sounds like it should be stupid simple, but my searches aren't yielding any luck.  Desktop browsers do this just fine when I resize with ctrl+=-/=, but pinch zoom on mobile browsers doesn't give me this friendly behavior.

Maybe what I want is for pinch zoom to actually increase the font size?  Do mobile browsers support this?